# Does the quake heap invariant hold after insertion?

Tags: data-structures

In section 2 of http://tmc.web.engr.illinois.edu/heap_ianfest.pdf, Chan writes that for some alpha in (1/2, 1), the number of nodes at height (i + 1), n_{i+1} to be at most alpha * n_i, the number of nodes at height i.

If I start with the complete binary tree consisting of three nodes and an edge graph, the invariant holds (2 nodes at height 2 and 3 nodes at height 1). But inserting a node will result in 4 nodes at height 1 and the invariant no longer holds. Is this right?

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding of this is correct. The invariant applies specifically after a call to `delete-min()` when any non-conforming trees are broken up to restore the invariant.

The trick to reconciling this with the rest of the analysis is noting where the invariant is required for the data structure to function.

The invariant is responsible for showing that the maximum height of a tree is no more than log_{1/alpha}(n). Note that if you have a configuration of the data structure that conforms to the invariant, such as your 3 node edge graph example, and you `insert()` another node (or alternatively, call `decrease-key()`), there cannot be any tree in the resulting configuration that has a height greater than log_{1/alpha}(n).

The other place that the invariant is used is in the amortized analysis for `delete-min()`, after which the invariant by definition holds.